# How to move every node to its own subdomain with Drupal?

Tags: path-aliases

I have a content site that was affected by Google Panda, and [recently it was suggested](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=panda%20subdomain) that it is advised by Google that moving content to subdomains might work.

Does anyone have a working solution to move aliased nodes to their subdomains so
mysite.com/subfolder/my-great-content
moved to
my-great-content.mysite.com ?

I found this but seems to be abandoned:
http://drupal.org/project/subdomain

Also this which is very advanced:
http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains

Or is multisite the way to go? I notice drupalgardens.com has subdomains for user pages.

Also found another method that uses the PURL module for Open Atrium, described here: https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/708
I guess this could be combined somehow with a wildcard subdomain setup? I notice it even has a subordomain module
http://drupal.org/project/subordomain

Here is a general solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943356/creating-subdomains-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/domain is probably the way to go.  You can do subdomains/multisites and specify exactly what tables be to shared from the database.  [This video](http://www.archive.org/details/SharingcontentacrossmultiplesiteswithDomainAccess)
is good documentation on what the module can do and how to integrate it.

Comment: Much appreciated will watch that. Meanwhile I am trying to catch some fish in the issue queue over there as well http://drupal.org/node/1241926

Comment: It seems this wont be possible with domain, here is the response from the author: http://drupal.org/node/1241926

Answer (score 2):

A couple years later... I have a similar requirement.

The Subdomain Field module works well for me. https://drupal.org/project/subdomain_field

Has clear installation instructions: edit your `settings.php`, update your virtual host, add a wildcard DNS record. Then simply install the module and add a "Subdomain Field" field type to any content types that you want.

Now when I edit `/node/2` and change the subdomain, I have `subdomain.example.com` displaying the contents of node 2. Perfect!

Note that it requires the Entity API module, but that is currently not listed as a "requirement"

Comment: That's what I needed once in a while. Good catch. Got no problems with Apache?

Comment: Nope, installation was smooth